# data.table index of a second column

Tags: r, data.table

I have two categorical columns (A,B) and numerical column (C). I want to obtain the value of A where C is the maximum of groups defined by B. I'm looking for a data.table solution.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table( A = c("a","b","c"), 
                  B = c("d","d","d"), 
                  C = c(1,2,3))
dt
   A B C
1: a d 1
2: b d 2
3: c d 3

# I want to find the value of A for the maximum value
# of C when grouped by B
dt[,max(C), by=c("B")]
   B V1
   1: d  3

#how can I get the A column, value = "c"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `which.max` to find the index of the maximum of `C` and select the corresponding element in `A`:

```
dt[,.(A=A[which.max(C)]), B]
#   B  A
#1: d  c
```

Comment: nice! now I'm cooking with gas.

Comment: or `.(A=A[which.max(C)])` to keep `A` which corresponds to dataframe rownames in my real data

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to sort by `C` and just extract the unique `B` groups. This should be faster for a big data set with many groups because it doesn't calculate maxima per group, rather sorts only once

```
unique(dt[order(-C)], by = "B")
#    A B C
# 1: c d 3
```